# How to modify the captions position in ROKU?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I try to display a closed caption in Roku. But close caption display in video anywhere not fix it. Does anyone know to fix a position in closed caption like any other XML components in Roku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closed caption (including target position, afaik) comes with the video,
Here's the roku documentation and there's no mention of setting position https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/developer-program/media-playback/closed-caption.md so, you can't position it, sorry.